# why must edits be at least six characters?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits, character-limit

I just attempted to correct a typo in the mathjax of a question. it was merely a case of a slightly misplaced }. which was correctly used in similar expressions throughout the rest of the text. the message I received was

Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

there may be some good reason motivating such a rule, but it clearly militates against notational accuracy, which is critical in mathematics.

the impact of this on a relatively new user like myself, with the motivation to assist  but feeling a little uncertain, is a discouraging impression of an arbitrary and counterproductive authoritarianism. e.g. why 6 rather than 5 or 7?

Comment: @T.Bongers I agree, the question you refer to deals with the same issue. happy for mine to be deleted

Comment: In commemoration of Weird Al's "This Song Is Just Six Words Long".